# java doesn't recognize so libraries

Tags: java, shared-libraries, bittorrent

I'm trying to develop a BitTorrent client using the frostwire jlibtorrent librari, but when I run the program alwais obtain the error on the image.

How I can compile using the linux version of the library.[image]

Comment: Hi do you run on linux or windows or Mac? The exception indicates that a binary lib can be loaded or found. (the .so file as you indicate).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi do you run on linux or windows or Mac? The exception indicates that a binary lib can be loaded or found. (the .so file as you indicate).
There is a case the native lib included in the jar - is not compatible or has missing dependencies (links) on your host OS. See [here](https://github.com/frostwire/frostwire-jlibtorrent/issues/50).

Answer (score 0):

The .so library has to be loaded first before it can be used. Use System.load() to do so. Here is an example:
https://www.chilkatsoft.com/java-loadLibrary-Linux.asp